# Slicing the cake to equal pieces

Tags: geometry

I think a lot of people on this channel are aware of the Cake Slicing Problem, whereby with *n* cuts to get a maximum number of pieces...

I was wondering, is there a way to achieve this, but ensuring equal size pieces in relation to surface area (focusing on the top of the cake, ie. dividing the circle)...

Is there a formula or algorithm with which to achieve pieces of equal area?

Comment: I haven't read this, but it might help: https://www.quantamagazine.org/new-algorithm-solves-cake-cutting-problem-20161006/

Comment: @Dr.Mathva While this is an interesting approach, I'm referring to the division of a circle by _n_ cuts... ie. 1 cut provides 2 pieces, 2 cuts provides 4 pieces, 3 cuts - 8 pieces , 4 cuts - 11 pieces etc. but ensuring that equal areas are achieved... I'm not concerned with the cake's trim or icing, or preferred pieces as per the article...

Comment: @Dr.Mathva: This is not a fair division problem, as OP points out...

Comment: Not ready for a full answer, but: For one or two cuts, obviously, the answer is yes, with the natural symmetric cuts. For three cuts, I suspect the answer is no; the first two cuts must leave at least one wedge with area $\pi/7$ (three cuts yields seven pieces, not eight), and must also leave the other three regions with area $2\pi/7$ each (*each* of them to be sliced in half by the last cut). I find it unlikely that one can find a satisfactory location for even the first two cuts, let alone the third. But I'll look.